# How to build a while loop that will stop when I reach to some hour that I set to myself inside the program? (Python3)

Tags: python, datetime, time, libraries

**Python 3.7**

I tried to create a program that will ask the user math questions until the time that the user sets to himself.
This is how I want the code work:

```
while current_time != ending_time:
    #Do stuff
```

My problem is how to set the `current_time` and the `ending_time` (I know how the "Do stuff" part will work).

So, in smaller questions:

1) Which function do I need to import from which libraries?

2) How to ask the user to enter a time to stop practicing?

3) How to set a variable that will hold the `current_time`?

Comment: Most of your problems would be solved by looking at the documentation for the `datetime` module: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.datetime

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the module "Time".

```
import time

currentTime = time.time()

userInput = input("How long to practice?")

# Do some checks and math on userInput to get endTime.

while currentTime < endTime:
    currentTime = time.time()
```

Get user input however which way you like (maybe using input()?) and do the math for end_time and do the loop as you're expecting but not with an equal comparison since it will never be 100% identical if you're using floats or nanoseconds.

Answer (score 0):

using datetime modeule

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta,date
start=datetime.now().time()
delta = timedelta(hours = 1) # hours will be user input
end=(datetime.combine(datetime.now(),start) + delta).time()
while start<=end:
    print('you got time :)')
# continue
```